# MVVMCross how to use same events

Tags: xamarin.ios, model-binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a View with 2 textbox and a button that call an action on a ViewModel to show another View; that what will show in it depends on values of 2 texbox.

For that reason before to call my ViewModel i want to check textbox values and if its are empty show a Dialog. Now to call my ViewModel i have add a binding like this:

```
 this.AddBindings(new Dictionary<object, string>()
        {

        { btnSearch, "TouchUpInside GoParameterizedCommand" },
        });
```

as Swiss Binding. Now if i want to use same event to check if my textbox are valorized and don't call GoParameterizedCommand, how could i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind all your controls to ViewModel properties like:

```
this.AddBindings(new Dictionary<object, string>()
{
    { btnSearch, "TouchUpInside GoCommand" },
    { text1, "Text MyText" },
    { switch1, "On MyOption" },
   // ...
};
```

Then inside the `GoCommand` handler you could put whatever logic you need:

```
public ICommand GoCommand
{
  get
  {
     return new MvxCommand(() => {
          if (MyOption)
          {
              ShowViewModel<OptionViewModel>();
          }
          else
          {
              ShowViewModel<DetailViewModel>(new { text = MyText });
          }
      });
   }
 }
```

For showing a dialog - eg an error dialog - then this might be best done using a messenger - sending an error message from the viewmodel. There are a few questions on here about error handling - eg http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/one-pattern-for-error-handling-in.html - plenty of other options are available for giving the user a hint about what to do - eg you could bind the background colour of the text field to an `IsMyTextValid` property.

Comment: And if i wanna do that on the View?

Comment: Sorry - your question isn't making complete sense to me. But I think the simplest answer is: if you want to write code-behind directly in the viewcontroller, then of course you can - just write the code, and call methods on the controls and the `ViewModel` as and when you want to.